# 'Keywords' is not a namespace-name

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, poco-libraries

I'm a half decent Java/C# programmer struggling with C++/PoCo.

All the examples I have seen so far have the same line. 
using namespace Poco::Data::Keywords;
In QT, the "Keywords" part is black. I don't know what to "#include" if that would fix it. Codeblocks also fails with the same error => 'Keywords' is not a namespace-name

A small example:

```
#include <Poco/Format.h>
#include <Poco/Data/MySQL/MySQLException.h>
#include <Poco/Data/Session.h>
#include <Poco/Data/MySQL/Connector.h>
using namespace Poco::Data::Keywords;

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried this on a couple of computers. Present one is an Ubuntu 15.10, updated and with the following packages (includes libpoco) + MySQL Client/Server/Workbench.

```
    1  sudo apt-get install build-essential 
    2  sudo apt-get install qtbase5-dev qtbase5-dev-tools qtbase5-doc   qtbase5-doc-html qtbase5-examples qtbase5-examples-dbg
    3  sudo apt-get install qt5-default qt5-doc-html qt5-doc
    4  sudo apt-get install openssl libssl-dev libssl-doc 
    5  sudo apt-get install libpoco-dev
```

Comment: Did you try to grep _namespace Keywords_ in the include dir of Poco ? or _Keywords::_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your library version is older then the one from actual docs you are using.
Try this command to find the version:

```
grep "POCO_VERSION" /usr/include/Poco/*.h
```

For me it outputs:

```
/usr/include/Poco/Foundation.h:#define POCO_VERSION 0x01030600
```

Which mean that poco is only 1.3 ( which does not have Keywords namespace yet ) and not 1.5 ( which does have it ).

If you need latest Poco you can download and install it manually, not using apt.

Comment: Thx. Autoremoved libpoco-dev. Manually installed the library and the keyword seems to be there and QT autocompletes "#include <Poc...." hints but I get an undefined reference to all libraries (not in the example). Not relevant to this question though. Thx again.

Comment: Well, you have to add library path to your local Poco installation, as now it is not in your system library path. If you using QtCreator simply add LIBS += /path-to-your-poco-libraries -lPocoNet and the other libraries as well.

Comment: It was something like that. Ended by me CTRL selecting all the PoCo libraries for the linker in CodeBlocks. All is well. Thx againagain.