# 'class Poco::XML::Element' has no member named 'getNodeByPath'

Tags: c++, qt, poco, openframeworks, poco-libraries

I am trying to set up openFrameworks with QT, but it seems that i had no success so far. I included all the necessary files i.e. includes, libs etc, but as soon as i compile the program it's showing an error

```
/home/kalyan/of_v0.9.3_linux64_release/libs/openFrameworks/utils/ofXml.h:204: error: 'class Poco::XML::Element' has no member named 'getNodeByPath'
                             Poco::XML::Element *e = (Poco::XML::Element*) element->getNodeByPath(path);
                                                                                    ^
```

I even asked in openFrameworks forum, but haven't got any reply.

I am running an example "3dPrimitivesExample" that has been included in openFrameworks build. I built that particular example using make, it generated object files and finally generated an .exe file.

Answer (score 1):

Are you having the same problem I had last week? Old version?

See here:
['Keywords' is not a namespace-name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36789269/keywords-is-not-a-namespace-name)

There is an excellent writeup on how to link QT to Poco using CMAKE in this link here (I never figured out how to do it using QMake):
[Clion, cMake and POCO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30114662/clion-cmake-and-poco)

Comment: Yeah, finally i gave up and started using the project generator that they supplied with openFrameworks. I went through the QBS file, since i am new to QBS i couldn't figure out what mistake i did when linking libraries. 
Thanks anyway i will give it a try once more, by not using QT qmake and using cmake for compiling.

Comment: You can use CMAKE with QT by creating a Non-QT project and selecting CMAKE when the default QMAKE is given in the project creation wizard. The second link I sent has to be edited so that you link to the .h and .so files that you create using the PoCo Make process.

Comment: My CMakeLists `code` project(Demo)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
aux_source_directory(. SRC_LIST)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -g")
set(DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST})
set(POCO_PREFIX "/home/YOURDIR/poco-1.7/cmake_install/debug")
set(POCO_INCLUDE_DIR "${POCO_PREFIX}/include")
set(POCO_LIB_DIR "${POCO_PREFIX}/lib")
set(POCO_LIBS "${POCO_LIB_DIR}/libPocoDataMySQLd.so"
#Add other required .so
)
target_include_directories(Demo PRIVATE "${POCO_INCLUDE_DIR}")
target_link_libraries(Demo "${POCO_LIBS}")
`code`